# Subscribe to a continuous data with angular-websocket

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I'm doing an Angular app for show a data continuously sent for a spring Server. My Angular App is connecting correctly, but I don't know how to make the subscription to the data the server is sending. I show you my code:

**Server, WebSocketConfiguration**:

```
...
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry){
        registry.addEndpoint("/random")
        .setAllowedOrigins("*")
        .withSockJS();
    }
....
```

**Server, DataGenerator**:

```
...
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Component
public class JapcDataGenerator implements ApplicationListener<BrokerAvailabilityEvent> {
[...]
public void sendDataUpdates(int val) {
        System.out.println("sending : " + val);
        this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/data", val);
    }
...
```

**Client, index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>WebSocket chart example</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="WebSocketAngularApp">
        <div ng-controller="socktCtrl">
            <p>{{data}}</p>
        </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-websocket/angular-websocket.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/application.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Client application.js**:

```
var socktApp = angular.module('WebSocketAngularApp',['ngWebSocket']);

socktApp.factory('mySockt',function($websocket){
    var ws = $websocket('ws://137.138.245.169:8888/serverEx/random/websocket');
    var collection = [];

    ws.onMessage( function(message){
        console.info("message: ", message);
        collection.push(JSON.parse(message.data));
    });

    ws.onOpen( function(message){
        console.log("Connection open!",message);
    });

    ws.onClose( function(){
        console.log("Closing the socket.")
    });

    ws.onError( function(message){
        console.info("Error in socket", message);
    });

    var methods = {
        collection: collection,
        get: function(){
            ws.send( JSON.stringify({action: 'data'}) );
        }
    };
    return methods;
});

socktApp.controller ('socktCtrl', function($scope, mySockt){
    $scope.data = mySockt;
});
```

The result shows the connection log, but never the message because I don't know how to do the subscription to this flow of data (the line: `this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/data", val);`).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ws.on('message', function...`

`message` being the event name emited from server.

Comment: I had tried Andrew, but what I receive is:
`angular.js:13550 TypeError: ws.on is not a function`
Thank you for the request.

Comment: I'm using angular-socket-io v0.7.0, My socketFactory looks like this: ...

...

    .factory(['socketFactory', function (socketFactory) {
         var mySocket = socketFactory();
         return mySocket; 
}]);

And then within any controller, I use my SocketFactory.on('event_name', function...

And everything works great, are you able to test it out ?

Comment: I have made in other try with it, but when I attempt to connect my server: `io.connect('ws://137.138.245.169:8888/serverEx/random/websocket');`; it gives me the next error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://137.138.245.169:8888/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LIWPK4v`. It doesn't connect, I asked the other method because I consider it was more advanced, because this even doesn't connect.

Comment: take a look at ngSocket, and try to implement it. It would then work fine.

Comment: I'll try, but according with documentation it is the same that angular-websocket, so I'll have the same problem I guess:
[angluar-socket](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket)
[ngSocket](https://github.com/angular/ngSocket)